# How do you check the category of the next/previous post?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm working on a wordpress site with several categories, where each of those categories have posts. Example: I have "Work" and "Careers" as two categories.
When you click on a "Work" post, at the top of the page there is a "Previous / Next" button to display the next or previous post with the category "Work". Right now, the code is set up like this:

```
        <div class="campaign__previous l-campaign__previous">

            <?php previous_post_link('%link','Previous Campaign', TRUE); ?>

        </div>

        <span>/</span>

        <div class="campaign__next l-campaign__next">

            <?php next_post_link('%link','Next Campaign', TRUE); ?>

        </div>
```

The wordpress function next_post_link('%link','LINK TEXT', TRUE) automatically doesn't display the link if there are no more posts in that category. That's great, but I also want to not display the

```
<span>/</span>
```

if there are no more posts in that category. How do I check this myself? I have tried:

```
if( next_post_link('%link','Next Campaign', TRUE) ) {
   echo '<span>/</span>';
}
```

This did not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For WordPress functions that print something to the screen automatically, there is usually a version with the prefix `get_` that will simply return the value. I don't have the ability to test this now but I assume the following might work or at least get you close:

```
if( get_next_post_link('%link','Next Campaign', TRUE) == "" )
    // No More
else
    // More to Come
```

Now there definitely seems like there is a better way to do this but this was just the first thing I thought of when I read your code.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_next_post_link/

Comment: Thanks a lot! I don't have the ability to test this until Tuesday, but it seems like it would help. I'll definitely try it and let you know!

Comment: This worked! The exact code is:

`if( (!get_next_post_link('%link','Next Campaign', TRUE) == "") && (!get_previous_post_link('%link','Next Campaign', TRUE) == "") ){
    echo '<span>/</span>';
   }`

Thanks a bunch!